# Let G be a group s.t $g^3=e$ for all g in G. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group s.t $g^3=e$ for all $g$ in $G$. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

From here I have got $(ab)^2=(b^2)(a^2)$ & $(ab)^3=a((ba)^2)b$
Then what??

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to prove something that is not true?

Answer (score 3):

The claim is wrong. Consider the [Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mathbb{Z}/3 & \mathbb{Z}/3 \\ 0 & 1 & \mathbb{Z}/3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. It is a non-abelian group of order $27$ and satisfies $g^3=1$ for all $g$.